# Ubuntu versions in Login loop, even the terminal window

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

I have tried installing various versions of Ubuntu on Udoo board but each time after installation the operating system ends up in a login loop, even the terminal window launched after the combination of `ctrl+alt+f3` is stuck in the loop. I believe that this might seem to be a duplicate question at once but in each scenario for all the users in nearly all the questions at least the terminal seems to work fine for login. Also I have tested the compatibility of the OS with the SBC by installing it on another similar board and everything works fine. I have tried installing Ubuntu 18.04, 16.04, Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 and 16.04 but each time the result seems to be the same. However, things seem to work fine in the guest mode for MATE.

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590561/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem)?

Comment: yes, But I couldn't  use any suggestions in it as I am not able to login even via terminal, and without logging in I can not execute any commands.

Comment: Any error messages? What bootloader do you have? Can you modify the boot command line to include `init=/bin/bash`, so you can see the logs?

Comment: yes I can boot to single user mode using the init=/bin/bash , do not know where to look for the error logs !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue happened with me few months back. Issue was with my current user through which I was trying to login. I logged into a single user mode and created a new user and try log in using new user which solved my issue. I know it's a hack but it worked :)

P.S. I'm not sure about the exact reason why it was failing with old user and working with new one.